# Wordpress jQuery - submit form on page load

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, submit

I have added a Store Locator plugin to a wordpress site and enabled it. The form action relies on jQuery as it bring up a map from Google showing the closest stores.

The client wants a sidebar containing a form with a postcode input that will redirect to the stores page and fill in the postcode input. I am wondering if there is any way to check if the length of the input (on the stores page) and if it isn't empty, auto submit the form.

Essentially, if a user searches for a postcode using the sidebar, when the store page loads and fills in the postcode input it should auto submit the form and  display the results (rather than the user having to click submit again)

Comment: Seems pretty standard. You should be catching the input on a separate page checking for `$_POST['value']`. Perform a conditional statement against the `$_POST['value']` to see if it's empty or not, if it's not empty, then `$.submit()` whatever the form is.

Comment: I have tried
if ($('#addressInput').length > 0) 
 {
  $('#searchForm').submit();
 }

Comment: I have got the value of the sidebar input into a variable and a conditional statement to add it to the store page input. Just need to submit the form